# Intel XDK + Ember - bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js: Unexpected token (45:0)

Tags: ember.js, babeljs, intel-xdk

I'm trying to use Ember + Intel XDK.

I create a brand new Ember app:

```
ember new cash
```

Run ember server, and go to localhost:4200 - everything ok - Welcome to Ember page appears.

Then I open Intel XDK and import my Ember HTML project. I just import it, go back to console and run ember server again. Then I get:

```
cash git:(master) ✗ ember server
version: 2.3.0
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
File: cash/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js
cash/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js: Unexpected token (45:0)
SyntaxError: cash/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js: Unexpected token (45:0)
  43 | // you try to trace through "use strict" call chains. (#13335)
  44 | //"use strict";
> 45 |
     | ^
at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:425:12)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:236:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:217:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:163:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:145:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:112:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:79:19)
at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/Antonio/Code/mbcash/cash/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:137:23)
```

I'm using ember-cli 2.3.0, which leads me to:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 2.3.1
DEBUG: Ember Data : 2.3.3
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.4
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I tried to use the following in ember-cli-build.js:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    babel: {
      compact: false
    }
  });
  return app.toTree();
};
```

but when I run ember server, I got these two lines:

```
version: 2.3.0
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
```

and it stops there.

If I go to the browser and visit localhost:4200, nothing happens, and the browser status bar shows:

```
Waiting for localhost...
```

I think I'm trying something new, because I searched a lot, but didn't find discussions about Ember + Intel XDK.

If somebody can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Babel is compiling the `bower_components` directory which is not good. Maybe **bower** is configured to create a `bower_components` directory inside your project's `app` dir.

Check if you have a `.bowerrc` file in your home directory (or upwards the directory tree of your project location) that looks like this:

```
{
"directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

If this is the case, delete the `app/bower_components` directory and create a local `.bowerrc` file in your project's directory.

Finally, run `bower install` if required.
Babel should not compile files inside `bower_components` the next time you run the server.